# Improve Parallel Cache with Reactive Extensions & Unity Interception

Tags: c#, optimization, cache, system.reactive

[image]

The requirement is to be able to cache method invocations made on a boundary layer (Services layer). I'm using Unity to inject the concrete implementation of the Service layer classes. The intercepting `CacheCallHandler` caches all the responses across this layer.

The twist is that this is a multi-threaded environment with multiple clients invoking the same boundary layer in the context of a single request. If a service layer call is already in "flight", it should wait for the original invokers return and use that.

I've used Reactive extensions to implement this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Intercepts the calls and tries to retrieve from the cache
/// </summary>
class CacheCallHandler : ICallHandler
{

    [Dependency]
    public ICache RequestCache { get; set; }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        IMethodReturn mesg = null;

        string cacheKey = CacheKeyGenerator.GetCacheKey(input);

        //create the task to retrieve the data
        var task = new Task<IMethodReturn>(() =>
        {
            return getNext()(input, getNext);
        });

        //make it observable
        var observableItem = task.ToObservable();

        //try to add it to the cache
        //we need to do this in the order of Add and then try to get, otherwise multiple thread might enter the same area
        if (RequestCache.TryAdd(cacheKey, observableItem))
        {
            //if the add succeeed, it means that we are responsible to starting this task
            task.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            if ( RequestCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out observableItem) )
            {
                //do nothing, the observable item is already updated with the requried reference
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CacheHandlerException("Could not add to cache AND could not retrieve from cache either. Something's wrong", input);
            }
        }

        //observe the return 
        if ( observableItem != null )
            mesg = observableItem.FirstOrDefault();

        if (mesg == null)
            throw new CacheHandlerException("Not return value found. this should not happen", input);

        return mesg;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Should always be the first to execute on the boundary
    /// </summary>
    public int Order
    {
        get { return 1; }
        set { ; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally i believe that there is no need for the reactive framework in this scenario.
To handle the multithreaded nature of your problem i would first make sure that your RequestCache (Icache) uses the ConcurrentDictionary> and exposrts the [method GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx)

With this your code will look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Intercepts the calls and tries to retrieve from the cache
/// </summary>
class CacheCallHandler : ICallHandler
{

    [Dependency]
    public ICache RequestCache { get; set; }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        return InvokeAsync.Result;
    }

    public Task<IMethodReturn> InvokeAsync(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        IMethodReturn mesg = null;

        string cacheKey = CacheKeyGenerator.GetCacheKey(input);

        //create the task to retrieve the data
        var task = RequestCache.GetOrAdd(
               cacheKey,
               key => new Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getNext()(input, getNext))
               );

        return task;       
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Should always be the first to execute on the boundary
    /// </summary>
    public int Order
    {
        get { return 1; }
        set { ; }
    }
}
```

The asynchronous version offers the option of to blocking the calling thread when invoking it.